# Getting the nesting heirarchy for any given module in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a method which needs to be able to access the nesting hierarchy of a module definition. Suppose I have this definition:

```rb
module A
  module B
    module C
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to write a method such that, if a reference to `C` is passed to the method, it is able to return the result of `Module.nesting` as if it was called inside the definintion. For example:

```
get_nesting(A::B::C) # => [A::B::C, A::B, A]
```

However, I can't figure out how to call `Module.nesting` in a different context. I've tried using `instance_exec`, but this just returns the nesting in the current scope.

```rb
module X
  def self.get_nesting(m)
    m.instance_exec { Module.nesting }
  end
end

X.get_nesting(A::B::C) # => [X]
```

I want this to return `[A::B::C, A::B, A]` instead.

Is there a way to get the nesting for a module in this way, using `Module.nesting` or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
module A
  module B
    module C
      Module.nesting
    end
  end
end
  #=> [A::B::C, A::B, A]

module A::B
  module C
    Module.nesting
  end
end
  #=> [A::B::C, A::B]
```

The reason `A` is not included in the last return value is that `nesting` depends on the structure of the code ("lexical") and not on the parent-child relationships of the modules. For that reason I think any method that causes `self` to equal the given module (the method's argument), and then execute `Module.nesting`, is doomed to failure.

You can, however, do the following.

```
def get_nesting(mod)
  a = mod.to_s.split('::')
  a.size.times.map { |i| Module.const_get(a[0..i].join('::')) }.reverse
end
```

```
get_nesting(A)       #=> [A] 
get_nesting(A::B)    #=> [A::B, A] 
get_nesting(A::B::C) #=> [A::B::C, A::B, A] 

get_nesting(A::B::C).map { |m| m.class } 
  #=> [Module, Module, Module]
```

Considering that this depends on [Module#to_s](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-to_s), this would be classified as a kludge.